# Multipage tiff file size grows linearly

Tags: compression, tiff, multipage

The following (simplified) C# code creates a multi page tiff file:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
var tiffBitmapEncoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    tiffBitmapEncoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Zip;
    foreach (.....)
    {
        //Generate the image to add to tiff
        .....
        var bitmapSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(.....));
        tiffBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
    }
    tiffBitmapEncoder.Save(ms);
}
```

The compression seems to be done on each frame/bitmap individually.
Therefore the file size grows linearly by the number of frames/bitmaps.

Is there a way to compress the tiff file as a whole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to compress the tiff file as a whole?

Short answer: No. TIFF images are always compressed per image/tile/strip.

Small print: It's possible for JPEG-encoded TIFF files to share tables, this could potentially perform better than linear growth, but I don't think this is what you are looking for.

You can of course create an uncompressed TIFF file, and compress it all using `gz`, `zip` or similar tools. However, it won't be a TIFF file any more. And I doubt it will compress better than TIFF with ZIP/Deflate + Predictor.